# How to create a home screen icon of URL, which is getting redirected

Tags: iphone

I have a google drive link on which when I tap, it shows me the file.

Now the problem is when I make an icon of it on my home screen, it stops working after some time.

So, How do I create an icon of such a link, which gets redirected to a different URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across such a scenario and following steps worked for me.

1. Go to screen where the google drive link is present.
2. Now Go to airplane mode.
3. Tap on google drive link.
4. Tap on "Add to Home screen".

Done!!!